# Star Wars fan website with false claims

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, fan-fiction

I recall around 2001-2003 time period there was a fan-created *Star Wars* website that made a lot of claims about the *Star Wars* universe, supposedly through insider knowledge/sources. The site opened after the initial theatrical release of Episode I, but before Episode II.

Some examples of the "insider" claims were:

- Yoda was originally thought to be the Chosen One who would bring balance to the Force.
- There were allegedly yellow lightsabers that were strong enough to cut through all other lightsabers.

There were many others that I can't recall.

It turned out **many of his claims were false**, and I think many fans in the *Star Wars* community called him out for making up stories and publishing them on his site. He was essentially riding off of *Star Wars* fans' excitement over the new *Star Wars* movies that were being released. I may have found out about it through [TheForce.net](https://www.theforce.net).

I can't recall this person's handle or website. I don't think he was publishing any of this on any forum; he used his website for all his stories. He may have had the word "Dark" somewhere in his handle. Does anyone remember this individual and/or website?

Comment: identify-this-website? I feel this may be off topic. Alternatively you might try asking in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Xantex I thought this would fit under historical fandom information. This is what I recall beyond a simple comment in forum, but a full blown website that many SW fans read/criticized. This was also before there was a SW wiki.

Comment: The question has been answered, so why not leave it? It could be useful to someone.

Comment: Sorry late to this party, I had one of thoses yellow lightsabers, it was inflatable (http://www.vectis.co.uk/Page/ViewLot.aspx?LotId=66848). Thought it was naff when I got it as a present, but changed when I realised you could have real battles with it, and the other kids with the plastic beams would soon regret it when their blades buckled under the onslaught of the yellow beam.

Comment: Thank goodness no-one ever does stuff like that on the internet any more  

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Supershadow,](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SuperShadow) I believe. You can view his old (now defunct) site via the Wayback machine, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100111105533/http://www.supershadow.com/).

> *SuperShadow is the alias of a Star Wars fan who ran SuperShadow.com, a
> website that fabricated insider knowledge and claimed that SuperShadow
> was a close friend of George Lucas, and one of the leading Star Wars
> fan experts in history*
>
> ...
>
> *When the website was online, SuperShadow would often post so-called
> Star Wars news, images, FAQs, spoilers, and even plot outlines for
> future Star Wars films, many of which he claimed originated from
> George Lucas. This led to enough controversy that Lucasfilm's Pablo
> Hidalgo commented in Star Wars Insider 90, released in October 2006,
> that SuperShadow had "absolutely no relationship with Lucasfilm or
> George Lucas" and that the reports on the site "are complete
> fabrications." Hidalgo also revealed that Lucasfilm had "taken action
> against the site several times when it" solicited money from fans
> "under false pretenses."*

Comment: YES! This is it! Haha, "Dark"... I was waaaay off.

Comment: Well, shadows are often relatively dark.