# What were the midi-chlorian counts for the main characters in the films?

Tags: star-wars

So in Episode 1 they reveal that force sensitivity can be measured scientifically by counting midi-chlorian in your cells. Does anyone know the midi-chlorian counts of any of the main characters? The amount of detail in back stories in Star Wars is often so in depth that I wouldn't be surprised if the data were available somewhere.

Comment: Wow why would someone donwvote me for this question? That's egregious. Darth Egregious.

Comment: Some people tend to think that questions for which answers are not forthcoming are bad questions. That is of course absurd, but *this is the Internet* (TM).

Comment: Boo!  Hiss!  M-word!

Comment: And now I want to change my user name to Darth Egregious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, there is no such list.**

If you search this on google or anything, you will probably find this [Midichlorian Count List](https://web.archive.org/web/20050308092513/http://www.supershadow.com/starwars/midi.html) that originated from [Supershadow](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/SuperShadow#Midi-chlorian_list); A [Star Wars fan website famous for his false claims](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/star-wars-fan-website-with-false-claims).

An informed reader will find many inaccuracies in this list, like the high midi-chlorian count of non force-sensitive characters. For example Grievous is claimed to have a count of 11,900. There are also many entries for non-existent characters, like *Aenon Jurtis* or *Ce Ce Denowai*, that also appear on the supposedly *leaked scripts* that you will find on supershadow, but conveniently nowhere else.

Comment: _Way_ incorrect even at a glance: It references nonexistent material ("Ben Skywalker (Star Wars Episodes 7 8 9)")

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure; Just because there exists a false list doesn't prove that there cannot be a real one. I vaguely remember some weird computer terminal output in front of the young Obi-Wan in Episode 1 where he took the mid-count readings from. But I don't recall if it had any scale whatsoever.

Comment: @bitmask The point is there is not *known* list, but if you search for one, you will easily find a false one. Apart from Anakin's count, there is almost no official data anywhere. [Wookieepedia's Midi-chlorian article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian#Biology) got some references values, but nothing more. And Obi-Wan's [*weird computer terminal output*](http://images.wikia.com/starwars/images/b/bd/Midi_Count.jpg) was not really informative.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: Wait. Was Grievous force sensitive?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 no, Dooku tried to make him force sensitive via blood transfusion, but failed.