# In which book did Count Dooku try to make General Grievous Force-sensitive?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, star-wars-legends

I just [found out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27942/what-were-the-midi-chlorian-counts-for-the-main-characters-in-the-films/27943?noredirect=1#comment189175_27943) that Dooku once tried to make General Grievous Force-sensitive by blood transfusion, but failed.

In which *Legends* book can I find this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [my answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/49586/5184), this occurs in [Star Wars: The Eyes of Revolution](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eyes_of_Revolution), where Count Dooku uses the blood of Sifo-Dyas to keep General Qymaen jai Sheelal alive. When revived into his new body, Sheelal takes on the name "General Grievous"

Comment: I'll also note that based on what I've found about the story, I haven't seen anything indicating that Dooku intended to make Sheelal Force-sensitive. Dooku was just trying to keep him alive. *Grievous* was the one who thought the transfusion would make him Force-sensitive. I have not, however, read the book itself, so the posted synopses may not be entirely accurate.